# How do i attach debugger to a running process?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Formerly, i wrote code in `IntelliJ`. If i have an infinite loop, for example like the following

```
for(;;){
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

while numerous hello printing i can just press `atatch debugger` button and then my app stop at the place where i have been when i have pressed the button and now i can see the stack trace.

[image]

Then i tried to do the same thing in `android studio`. I ran my app and pressed `atatch debugger` button. To my surprise the app didn't stop and i didn't see any stact trace.

[image]

Common breakpoints work fine.

**So how can i get the same behaviour in `android studio` as `IntelliJ` have ? is it even possible ?**

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint?  Attaching the debugger doesn't automatically stop the process.  I don't think that would be particularly useful to do-  you'd be stopping at a random place which would more likely be not the main thread waiting in a message queue

Comment: @GabeSechan `Did you set a breakpoint?` no, i didn't. `Attaching the debugger doesn't automatically stop the process.` But in intellij it does